# Calculate percentage remaining of percentage

Tags: javascript, math

I'm making progress of several downloads, I load the first module which percentage is fixed at 70% and then load several other modules **where do i know the modules length after downloading the first module**, and so I try to fill in the 30% to complete 100% progress.

```
export default class ModuleLoader {
  private percent;
  private first_module_loaded;

  constructor() {
    this.percent = 0;
    this.first_module_loaded = false;
    this.loadFirstModule();
  }

  public updatePercentage(percent) {
    percent = Math.trunc(percent);

    if (this.first_module_loaded) {
      percent = Math.trunc((((percent / 100) * 0.3) * 100));; // here is
      this.percent += percent;
    } else if (!this.first_module_loaded && percent >= 70) this.percent = 70;
    else this.percent += percent;
  }

  public loadFirstModule() {
    //...load the first module
    //this.updatePercentage((bytesLoaded / bytesTotal) * 100)

    //after complete the percentage is fixed to 70%, and load other modules with the modules length retrieved from the first module
    this.first_module_loaded = true;

    this.loadOthersModules(modules_length);
  }

  public loadOthersModules(modules_length) {
    //...load others modules
    //this.updatePercentage(((bytesLoaded / bytesTotal) * 100) / modules_length)
  }
}
```

I tried `Math.trunc((((percent / 100) * 0.3) * 100))` but the percentage is always greater than 100 at the end

Comment: Math.floor() is what you should be using.

Comment: Without seeing how your actually loading your modules, this seems pretty inaccurate. You have access to the totalBytes to load and a count of bytesLoaded....